# How to import fonts from Fontastic.Me

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am trying to get my font from "Fontastic.me" working. I made a custom font but it isn't appearing.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

tbody{
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "cylexion";
  src:url("../fonts/cylexion.eot");
  src:url("../fonts/cylexion.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/cylexion.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/cylexion.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("../fonts/cylexion.svg#cylexion") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}

[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: "cylexion" !important;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "cylexion" !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-cylexion-a:before {
  content: "\61";
}
.icon-cylexion-ah:before {
  content: "\42";
}
.icon-cylexion-ai:before {
  content: "\44";
}
.icon-cylexion-aw:before {
  content: "\45";
}
.icon-cylexion-ay:before {
  content: "\41";
}
.icon-cylexion-b:before {
  content: "\62";
}
.icon-cylexion-c:before {
  content: "\63";
}
.icon-cylexion-d:before {
  content: "\64";
}
.icon-cylexion-e:before {
  content: "\65";
}
.icon-cylexion-ear:before {
  content: "\49";
}
.icon-cylexion-f:before {
  content: "\66";
}
.icon-cylexion-g:before {
  content: "\67";
}
.icon-cylexion-h:before {
  content: "\68";
}
.icon-cylexion-i:before {
  content: "\69";
}
.icon-cylexion-j:before {
  content: "\6a";
}
.icon-cylexion-k:before {
  content: "\6b";
}
.icon-cylexion-l:before {
  content: "\6c";
}
.icon-cylexion-m:before {
  content: "\6d";
}
.icon-cylexion-n:before {
  content: "\6e";
}
.icon-cylexion-o:before {
  content: "\6f";
}
.icon-cylexion-oh:before {
  content: "\46";
}
.icon-cylexion-oo:before {
  content: "\47";
}
.icon-cylexion-ow:before {
  content: "\48";
}
.icon-cylexion-p:before {
  content: "\70";
}
.icon-cylexion-q:before {
  content: "\71";
}
.icon-cylexion-r:before {
  content: "\72";
}
.icon-cylexion-s:before {
  content: "\73";
}
.icon-cylexion-t:before {
  content: "\74";
}
.icon-cylexion-u:before {
  content: "\75";
}
.icon-cylexion-v:before {
  content: "\76";
}
.icon-cylexion-w:before {
  content: "\77";
}
.icon-cylexion-x:before {
  content: "\78";
}
.icon-cylexion-y:before {
  content: "\79";
}
.icon-cylexion-z:before {
  content: "\7a";
}
.icon-cylexion-ee:before {
  content: "\43";
}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<h1> edd</h1>
<link href="{%  static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{% static 'fonts/cylexion.ttf' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{% static 'fonts/cylexion.eot' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{% static 'fonts/cylexion.svg' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{% static 'fonts/cylexion.woff' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<head>
    <title>a
    </title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="icon">Test</div>
<h1> header

</h1>
<p >goo</p>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried referencing them with `<div class="cylexion">"word"</div>`.

Comment: Your HTML does not contain any elements with class like `.icon-cylexion-...`.

Comment: Also links like `<link href="{% static 'fonts/cylexion.ttf' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` do not make sense as those fonts are neither `stylesheet` nor `text/css`